# Removing all punctuation from string in dataframe

Tags: python, nlp

This is officially doing my head in. I am web scraping a collection of tweets for text analysis. The tweets have been scraped and put into a dataframe, where each row is a string containing the entire tweet. I can't for the life of me remove quotation marks or apostrophes, but removing all other punctuation is OK.

What I am trying to do is extract just the verbs, nouns and adjectives from each of the scraped tweets, which I have done, but anything in quotation marks is excluded.

The code that I have been using so far is below, but I can't for the life of me add quotation marks or apostrophes. I have also tried every other method I can find on this site , but it either does nothing, or produces errors.

```
tweets['Text_processed'] = tweets['Text'].map(lambda x: re.sub('[,\@#.!?]', "", x))
```

The entire code base up until this point is:

```
import GetOldTweets3 as got
import pandas as pd
import re  
from wordcloud import WordCloud# Join the different processed titles together.
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", DeprecationWarning)# Load the LDA model from sk-learn
from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation as LDA
import os
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import gensim
from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
import logging
import tempfile
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from string import punctuation
from collections import OrderedDict
import pyLDAvis.gensim
import tempfile

%matplotlib inline

init_notebook_mode(connected=True) #do not miss this line
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

# Function that pulls tweets based on a general search query and turns to csv file
# Parameters: (text query you want to search), (max number of most recent tweets to pull from)

def text_query_to_csv(text_query, count):
    # Creation of query object
    tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch(text_query)\
                                                .setMaxTweets(count)
    # Creation of list that contains all tweets
    tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
    # Creating list of chosen tweet data
    text_tweets = [[tweet.date, tweet.text] for tweet in tweets]
    # Creation of dataframe from tweets
    tweets_df = pd.DataFrame(text_tweets, columns = ['Datetime', 'Text'])
    # Converting tweets dataframe to csv file
    tweets_df.to_csv('{}-{}-tweets.csv'.format(text_query, int(count)), sep=',')
```

```
############################################
# Search word and number of tweets to scrape
############################################

text_query = '#barackobama'

count = 5

# Calling function to query X amount of relevant tweets and create a CSV file
text_query_to_csv(text_query, count)

filename = '#barackobama-5-tweets.csv'

tweets = pd.read_csv(filename)

# Convert tweets to strings and lower case
tweets['Text'] = tweets['Text'].astype(str)
tweets['Text'] = tweets['Text'].map(lambda x: x.lower())

tweets
```

This is the offending bit of code below...

```
# remove punctuation
tweets['Text_processed'] = tweets['Text'].map(lambda x: re.sub('[,\@#.!?]', "", x)) 
tweets['Text_processed'].head()
```

```
#####################################
# Extract nouns, verbs and adjectives
#####################################

import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

from IPython.display import display
lemmatizer = nltk.WordNetLemmatizer()

def leaves(tree):
    """Finds NP (nounphrase) leaf nodes of a chunk tree."""
    for subtree in tree.subtrees(filter = lambda t: t.label() =='NP'):
        yield subtree.leaves()
        
def get_word_postag(word):
    if pos_tag([word])[0][1].startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    if pos_tag([word])[0][1].startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    if pos_tag([word])[0][1].startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    else:
        return wordnet.NOUN
    
def normalise(word):
    """Normalises words to lowercase and stems and lemmatizes it."""
    word = word.lower()
    postag = get_word_postag(word)
    word = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word,postag)
    return word

def get_terms(tree):    
    for leaf in leaves(tree):
        terms = [normalise(w) for w,t in leaf]
        yield terms
        
tidied_tweets = []
        
for t in tweets['Text']:
    #word tokenizeing and part-of-speech tagger
    document = t
    tokens = [nltk.word_tokenize(sent) for sent in [document]]
    postag = [nltk.pos_tag(sent) for sent in tokens][0]
    
    # Rule for NP chunk and VB Chunk
    grammar = r"""
        NBAR:
            {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  # Nouns and Adjectives, terminated with Nouns
            {<RB.?>*<VB.?>*<JJ>*<VB.?>+<VB>?} # Verbs and Verb Phrases
            
        NP:
            {<NBAR>}
            {<NBAR><IN><NBAR>}  # Above, connected with in/of/etc...
            
    """
    #Chunking
    cp = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)
    
    # the result is a tree
    tree = cp.parse(postag)
    
    terms = get_terms(tree)
    
    features = []
    for term in terms:
        _term = ''
        for word in term:
            _term += ' ' + word
        features.append(_term.strip())
        
    tidied_tweets.append(features)
    
tidied_tweets
```

The code base I have after this works OK, but the inability to remove quoted text or anything with an apostrophe is causing real problems.

**EDITED TO ADD**

I've managed to solve the problem, but in doing so, created another. The latest bit of code to extract the words sans the punctuation is:

```
tweet_list = []
ind_tweet = []

for tweets in tidied_tweets:
    for words in tweets:
        a = re.findall(r"[\w']+", words)
        ind_tweet.append(a)
    tweet_list.append(ind_tweet)
```

**re.findall(r"[\w']+", words)** does the job of extracting the word, but I can't create the same structured list I started with. What I wanted is 'tweet_list' to act as the parent list, and 'ind_tweet' to act as a sucession of child lists (nested). When I print out the result of the code above, I'm not able to create the nested list I am looking for. ind_tweet produces the output but in a single list with no nesting, and tweet_list duplicates ind_tweet. It probably isn't helping that it's 2:30am on a Saturday, but this should be much easier than I am making it...

Answer (score 0):

And the answer is...

```
tweet_list = [[] for i in range(len(tidied_tweets))]

for tweets, t in zip(tidied_tweets, range(len(tidied_tweets))):
    for words in tweets:
        a = re.findall(r"[\w']+", words)
        tweet_list[t].append(a)
```